# how do we enter date(date picker) on a web page using vba excel web scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm getting an error showing type mismatch when i use the following code to enter the date

```
Dim HTMLInp As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Set HTMLInp = HTMLDoc.getElementsById("startDate")
HTMLInp.Value = Worksheets("Menu").Range("a3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

```
HTMLDoc.getElementById("startDate")
```

The retrieval method is to return a single element without the `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the value

```
HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu").value = "YourDesiredValue"
```

or the selected index

```
HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu").selectedIndex = 1
```

Also try some of this:

```
    With .FindElementByCss("[data-test='date-picker-full-range']")
        .ScrollIntoView
        .Click
    End With
    With .FindElementByCss("[name=startDate]")
        .Clear
        .SendKeys "05/10/2017"
    End With

    With .FindElementByCss("[name=endDate]")
        .Clear
        .SendKeys "05/10/2017"
    End With
```

another source for info: `https://web.archive.org/web/20170802065959/www.vb-tips.com/MSHTML.aspx`